# Why are files from macs often encrypted when copied to a hard drive and viewed from Windows?

Tags: macos, encryption

Why are files from macs often encrypted when put on an external drive and that drive is plugged into a windows system?

I'll explain what I mean 'cos they don't look encrypted at first sight, as you can open them..

but on closer inspection, they can show up green in windows explorer

[image]

and the windows cipher command shows then as encrypted, and their attribute properties show as encrypted.

[image]

I'm not the only person that has run into this, looking for example [How to list encrypted files in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/58878/how-to-list-encrypted-files-in-windows-7)  one poster writes "... I was cleaning up a external hdd and came across 150 files that where encrypted. So I wanted to know what and where they were as I do not use a encryption on my computers. Turns out it was from a few downloads that I can easily get. Or seeing "_MACOSX" folders on my pc. They are always encrypted."

An example I ran into is a program I wrote in rails just a directory called "scaffoldingtest1" that I created with the command `rails new scaffoldingtest1`  and i'd have copied a parent directory to an external hard drive.

I've also seen some PDFs related to adobe, from Mac users.

And they're encrypted as if they were encrypted on the windows machine, in that they can only be viewed from that windows username @ that computer. As shown in the properties of the encryption in windows. And that user at that computer can decrypt them.   But they somehow got encrypted like that.  If that external drive were taken to another windows computer, then they can't be read.

And i'm wondering what setting on OSX is causing that?

Note- since some moderators have a tendency to delete long comment threads and lose important info, here is a link to the comment thread at the moment backed up here as of 21/11/2020 20:13 UK time https://pastebin.com/raw/f2Aytv6W

Comment: If they're not actually encrypted, then Windows is simply misinterpreting. Dot underscore files are extended attributes which have to be separated out because Windows doesn't know how to deal with them. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: @Tetsujin not just that ._ thing that guy mentioned.. I added some examples from my own experience and they're just regular named directories

Comment: What are you using to determine if a file is encrypted or not? Can you add an example to your question? It sounds like what you're seeing is the result of user permissions, which if that is the case is not the same as encryption.

Comment: If they're truly encrypted & windows can access them the same as any other Windows encrypted file, then Windows must have encrypted them. If the Mac had done it, then being able to simply decrypt on Windows would be a really really poor security measure.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are only looking at one aspect of this though, but there is a lot pointing to the idea that something going on at the Mac end is playing a role here. It's very suspicious that the only files that have this issue are from Macs, be it from a mac I have in the house, or from a lecturer that had adobe pdfs, another lecturer that had adobe after effects videos, and a friend that did web programming.. All mac users. All other directories and files were fine

Comment: We still don't know how you are identifying these files as encrypted. Usually on Windows files with names in green are compressed. Get Properties on the drive in question & see if it's set to compress

Comment: @Tetsujin  i'm not even aware of a compress option in windows, the encrypt checkbox is ticked  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfGLE.png  also https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ASQI.png  the cipher command in windows shows it's encrypted

Comment: OK, so that's a Windows setting - I fail to see how the  Mac could have any influence on that. That wasn't the place to check if the drive is set to compress though.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdNwV.png - that one not compressed, of course

Comment: @Tetsujin well I fail to see it too which is why I asked the question, but there's clearly some Mac thing going on there because it's only happening with files/folders from a mac, and the guy I linked to found the same thing (hence he mentioned decrypting with cipher command)

Comment: @Tetsujin so you mean that compressed option, no.  And we're talking here about individual files and folders on a drive. Not something affecting a whole drive (and encryption not compression)

Comment: What's crucial here is the difference between "Windows Tools think a file is encrypted" and "A file is actually encrypted". The file is not encrypted on the Mac side of things, it also isn't encrypted on Windows (otherwise you wouldn't be able to read it) so it must be something in its metadata which makes Windows Explorer think it is.

Comment: There are for sure people who know in detail how things work in Windows on this but you will find way more of those on SuperUser. I'm going to migrate the question.

Comment: This should not have been migrated to SuperUser, as it is really a Mac-related question.

Comment: @nohillside I couldn't read it unless I ran cipher /d on the file, from the machine that windows showed in its encryption properties

Comment: @jksoegaard It is a cross-OS issue. On AD we don‘t know what makes Windows think a file is encrypted.

Comment: @nohillside If the question was What makes windows treat a file as encrypted, then it'd be a windows question. If the question was What is it about Mac OSX that makes its files show up oddly on Windows machines, then it'd be a Mac OSX question.  OSX is still niche relative to Windows, so more likely an OSX user would know what was going on, re What Is It About Mac OSX that causes this or plays a role in this. And  lo and behold, the one person that has posted an answer to this, is a big guy on AD not on SO. No surprise.

Comment: @nohillside also, if computer A was to do something funny with a file that  computer B wasn't used to, then who is going to be best placed to figure out what's going on?  People that know about what computer A is doing. Computer A is the MAC.

Comment: @barlop Compressing and decompressing works without any issues on macOS, the problem comes from a conflicting use of some attributed in the zip file. There isn‘t anything funny on either side, but to figure it out it needs know-how about both OSes, something one for sure finds on SU but doesn‘t necessarily on AD.

Comment: Anyway, the important part is that there is an answer to the question which anybody can find in the future.

Comment: @nohillside The files may have been in a zip at some point but the files that are affected , once extracted, are not in a zip... the answer posted explains it

Comment: @nohillside You're right it's cross-OS, and I perhaps formulated myself too harshly there. I just meant that it didn't need to move off AD because it is also Mac-related... but it fits in on SU as well :-)

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion... this issue is really about a bug in the Windows unzipping utility. There's no doubt it is a Windows bug. However, Windows users are only going to come across this bug when they interact with users on other platforms, so for user's it is natural to assume that the bug is on the other platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this is a known compatibility issue with the built-in macOS Archive program and the built-in unzipper in various Windows versions.

When you use the "Compress" tool built-in to Finder, you'll get a ZIP-file. The ZIP-file contains, amongst other things, what is known as "external file attributes" for each file. These attributes are host-system dependent (i.e. these attributes are not guaranted to be understood the same way on various operating systems).

Unfortunately, one of the attributes that the macOS tools marks the files with are interpreted by the Windows built-in unzip tool as marking the file as "encrypted" (which is a special form of single-file encryption built-in to the NTFS file system). This means that when unzipped the files have the encrypted attribute and their names are shown in green in the Windows Explorer.

However, there are no significant downsides to this as you can easily open Properties on the files and remove the checkmark on the "encrypted" attribute. The file contents is not really encrypted, so the files can be opened as always.

You can avoid this issue by either using a different compression tool on the Mac, or by using a different decompression tool on Windows.

The technical details are as follows:

The problem is caused by the Windows unzipper incorrectly parsing the "external file attributes" in the ZIP-header for each file/folder. This element of the header is host-dependent, as such the unzipper should check the element of the centrall directory file header known as "Version made by" to inspect which operating system made the file. The macOS compression tool correctly stores the attribute value 3 for "Unix" here.

Unfortunately the Windows tool disregards this value and always interprets the file attributes as though they were created on Windows. The "encryption" issue comes from the fact that ZIP-files created on Windows stores file attributes according to the file attribute constants (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_<...>) defined by Microsoft. In particular FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED defined by the value 0x4000 means encrypted file or directory. However Unix-systems use the POSIX constants where S_IFDIR is the attribute that means "this is a folder" - and is typically defined as the value 0040000, which is equivalent to 0x4000.

Comment: I used to use a laptop a lot, username harvey, computer name samsung. And I had an external hard drive connected to that..It had some files from mac users/ mac laptops.  When I moved that external hard drive to another computer  user@probook (that's a windows laptop) , I could not open those files. They showed as encrypted by harvey@samsung (that's a windows laptop).  I had to decrypt them on my old harvey@samsung laptop. I was not able to untick the encrypted option otherwise. And cipher wasn't able to "decrypt" it except from the samsung350 laptop (which the file did show as being from).

Comment: You mention " there are no significant downsides to this as you can easily open Properties on the files and remove the checkmark on the "encrypted" attribute."  <-- Though see my comment above

Comment: So, I couldn't read it from a newer laptop that I plugged the hard drive into, unless I ran cipher /d on the file, from the machine that windows showed in its encryption properties

Comment: btw, interesting, I see https://superuser.com/questions/120354/analyzing-properties-of-a-zip-file  there's "file security status" (encrypted / not encrypted), and "file system or OS of origin" e.g. UNIX  so I guess I can see how that could go wrong

Comment: @barlop Yes, I meant no major downside as in "you can easily work around it when it happens"... ofcourse if you do not remove the checkmark, and keep the files around for long - and then later move them over to other systems again - you'll run into that issue.

Comment: @barlop No, that actually haven't got anything to do with this. The "file security status" you refer to means whether or not the file is encrypted within the zip-file. That is not the case here, and it is not the attribute that is being parsed incorrectly here.

Comment: thanks. what program or method would you suggest for viewing the attribute you speak of and other attributes?

Comment: You could use a standard hex-editor for example?

Comment: so i'm curious, what caused you to dig into a zip file header? just randomly decided to look at a zip header in a hex editor? or programming  involving zip? Also looking on the wikipedia page for zip header,  I can't see `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED` so what reading resource do you suggest to use for what the bytes mean with proper names, while looking in a hex editor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116535/discussion-between-barlop-and-jksoegaard).

Comment: @barlop I'm a programmer and have work with ZIP-files many times. The constant FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED is not part of the ZIP-header, so you cannot look it up there. It is a Windows specific and defined in winnt.h. Regarding reading resources it depends on your level of skill (home user, hobby programmer, expert, etc) - but the general resource for the ZIP format is: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Comment: (and note that it does not cover all extensions, host specific information, etc - but that's the way it is with zip)